# Launch a Storefront Session in Windows from Command Line

Tags: command-line-interface, citrix

I want to open a new Citrix Storefront session on a Windows 7 32 bit client from the command line by passing the store URL. I have the Citrix Receiver 4.2 installed.

On Linux the program "storebrowse" is available and does this. However I haven't found a similar way to open a Storefront URL on Windows.

I tried using SelfService as explained in the documentation: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX200337
But that didn't really work. Of course I can open the URL in Internet Explorer, but this is what I want to avoid.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
selfservice.exe -init -createprovider StoreName https://storefronturl...
selfservice.exe -showAppPicker -s StoreName
```